# Camera doesn't work in 2 chrome browsers opened in paralel from selenium project

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webcam

Here's the thing.
Create an app that opens a Google browser, navigates to some page and keeps the browser open.
If you run this app 2 times, the expected behaviour is that it will open 2 Chrome browsers (which it does).

Then, I manually go into one of the sites and click flash settings so it loads the webcam, **and it works**.
When I go to the second browser and click on the flash settings, **the camera doesn't load anymore**. If I try using a secondary camera, it works. But otherwise, if I try to use the first one, it fails and doesn't load it. (*p.s. it's a webcam splitter, I know that a USB camera can only be used once*).

**P.S. The same code used to work perfectly on chrome since version 46 (when I created that code) till version 72. *But now, with the release of v53, it is not working anymore*.**

P.S. The following are the options that I pass to the Chrome browser:

```
           // for each "whichSite", I have a preset saved chrome profile folder.

           if (Directory.Exists(profileDir))
           {
              opts.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=" + Path.Combine(Program.PROFILE_CHROME, whichSite));
              opts.AddArguments("--parent-profile=" + Path.Combine(Program.PROFILE_CHROME, whichSite));
           }

            opts.AddArguments("--window-size=1280, 720");

            opts.AddArguments("--allow-outdated-plugins");
            opts.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            opts.AddArguments("--always-authorize-plugins");
            if (versionInfo.ProductMajorPart < 65)
                opts.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            else
                opts.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation"); // this will show the debug extensions thing

            opts.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

            opts.AddArguments("--disable-translate");
            opts.AddArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
            opts.AddArguments("--new-window");
            opts.AddArguments("--no-experiments");
            opts.AddArguments("--no-first-run");

            opts.AddArguments("--disable-background-mode");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-session-crashed-bubble");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-suggestions-service");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-sync");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-spelling-auto-correct");
            opts.AddArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
            opts.AddArguments("--no-network-profile-warning");

            opts.AddArguments("--homepage=google.com");


            opts.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-new-profile-management");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-single-click-autofill");

            opts.AddArguments("--isolate-extensions");
            opts.AddArguments("--disable-settings-window");
```

Comment: I have discovered that the "--user-data-dir" might be the cause for the issue.

You can replicate this behavior if you open manually a chrome browser, and then you open a secondary one by passign the "--user-data-dir" parameter, with path to a separate copy of your chrome profile data.

If you chose a secondary available camera, it will work. But if you chose the camera that was already selected in first opened browser, it will not work anymore.

Comment: Reported a bug about this, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=950984